# Keep getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a code that goes to a webpage and enters text, and I coded it, but when I load the text I want and click start I get an System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
error. Heres my code:

```
        for (int index = 0; index < this.Messages.Count; index = checked(index + 1))
        {
            string[] str = this.Messages[index].Split(new char[]
            {
                ':'
            });

            using (HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest()) // am using xNet here and below
            {
                req.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
                req.Cookies = new CookieDictionary(false);
                req.Proxy = null;
                req.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;
                req.AddParam("message-user", str[0]);
                req.AddParam("message-wall", str[1]); //this is where the error occurs
```

Can someone help me fix this please? Thanks.

Comment: Your code is missing some text

Comment: It seems that you code is assuming that `str` has a length of 2 when that is not always the case.  Simple bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if any of the messages did not contain a colon. You'll need to check the length of the array, I.E.

```
req.AddParam("message-wall", str.Length > 1 ? str[1] : String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check wheter there is a ':' character or not. If your Message[index] doesn't have any ':' you'll only get one string in the array.
Take a look at this example test and feel free to fork/modify it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvwu0U